# iterating through private member of another class using friend function

Tags: c++, iterator, friend-function

I have declared a friend function inside the below class.

**Class model**

```
#include "fileio.h"
class fileio;
class model
{
    std::vector<element>m_elements;
    public:
    friend void fileio::element_iterator();
}
```

`element_iterator()` is a public function of the `class fileio`.

**Class fileio**

```
#include "model.h"
class model;
class fileio
{     
    model* m_model;
    public:
    fileio(model*);
    void element_iterator();
}
```

The `element_iterator()` function is defined as below.

```
void fileio::element_iterator()
{
    for(auto &iter : m_model->m_elements)
    {
        //some functions
    }
}
```

I want to iterate through the `m_elements` from another class using friend function. But I'm getting errors as below:

**ERRORS:**

```
 model.h : error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class fileio'
 friend void fileio::read_boundary();

 model.h : error: forward declaration of 'class fileio'
 class fileio; 

 modell.h : In member function 'void fileio::read_boundary()':

 cmodel.h : error: 'std::vector<element> model::m_elements' is private
 std::vector<element>m_elements;

 fileio.cpp: error: within this context
 for(auto iter:m_model->m_elements)
```

**EDIT**:
Without forward declaration of `class model` in the fileio.h  gives another set of errors as below:

```
error: 'model' has not been declared
 fileio(model*); 

 error: 'model' does not name a type     
      model* m_model;

 candidates are:
     fileio::fileio(int*)
     fileio(model*);
      no known conversion for argument 2 from 'model*' to 'int*'
```

If I comment out the friend function declaration and its definition, then the program will run without errors.
How do I solve it?

Comment: You need `#include "fileio.h"` instead of just `class fileio;` in `model.h`.

Comment: For the edit: Did you remove `class model;` in `fileio.h` too?

Comment: @songyuanyao, tried both the ways. didn't make any difference

Comment: Well, the code showed in @Vittorio Romeo's answer should work. Otherwise, you should provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to reproduce it.

Comment: @songyuanyao, Could you check the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *forward-declaring* `fileio` in `model.h`, include its full definition.

```
// fileio.h
class model;
class fileio
{
    model* m_model;
    public:
    void element_iterator();
};
```

```
// model.h
#include "fileio.h"
class model
{
    std::vector<int >m_elements;
    public:
    friend void fileio::element_iterator();
};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QVo2EDsSFpQTfv3a)

---

Alternatively, you could make the entire `fileio` class a `friend` - this would allow you to use its *forward-declaration*, which might be what you want depending on your real situation.

```
// model.h
class fileio;
class model
{
    std::vector<int >m_elements;
    public:
    friend class fileio;
};
```

```
// fileio.h
class model;
class fileio
{
    model* m_model;
    public:
    void element_iterator();
};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wZ0WUm8gfQS0ZeMG)

Comment: Program runs fine if I declare the model class as friend class to fileio class. But why I am not able to use friend function?